# bitbucket git commits missing

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-commit

We have migrated from svn to git lately. And I am not good with git till now. My problem is that, I have committed some files and it cause to lose the file changes others did. But the changes are there in my instance but not in any others(they  lost what they committed). The graph shows the details. The top two commits I have marked caused the issue. Please help me to resolve the issue. I am not using commands for git, but tortoise git UI.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not have a complete solution to your problem, but here's out of personal experiences with BitBucket. (Note: I use git client and commands for communicating with Bit Bucket)

At times when I see such an issue, the prime reason behind such a failure is either failure of 'git push' (which finally pushes your latest staged changes to the active branch), or selection of an incorrect branch while committing the code.

Ideally, in my case, I would fire a fresh (dummy) commit operation, and things work just fine for me. 
I agree that this is not a direct solution to your problem, but may be of help!

Comment: A coworker of mine believes that going a `git fetch` should produce the same result if you don't want to do a `commit` operation.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use git force push unless definitely required 
When you make your branch upto date by pull or merge ensure you accept the changed set - are you sure you are removing commit or are you promoting the older commit ? 
Mostly the later